# OkHttp 4.x giving error when trying to access url via Call request

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I recently started update to okhttp3 to 4.x

In doing so I am getting following build time error:

`Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val`

The issue is happening when I am trying to get url from request object obtained via call:

e.g

```
   call.enque(callback : Callback){
     override fun onFailure(call : Call, t:Throwable) {
       val url = call.request().url().toString
     }
   }
```

I looked up further and the `Url` object within `Request` is val aka final now.

Also, no directions on their upgrade guide https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/

I would appreciate for any suggestions on another way to obtain Url.

Comment: What programming language is this? Looks halfway between Java and Kotlin.

Comment: @JesseWilson this is kotlin, a JVM based language.

Comment: @Akshay the val would not try to stop you, you are not assigning a new value you are just accessing it. So in java terms you are not assigning a new value to the final variable you are just accessing it. Can you post a screen shot of the error log.

Comment: @JesseWilson My bad. That's what happens when your child class is Kotlin and base class is Java, and you copy paste without realizing it (disappear emoji here) . Syntax should now be fixed.

Comment: @war_Hero Thanks for your response. Accessing url would work if you access it in java class. However, Kotlin won't allow it since there are no getter/setters in Kotlin. So Kotlin doesn't know if you are accessing to set a value or to get it.

Comment: check the internet permission on manifest file

Comment: @RohitSoni that's fine, like I said, this only happened when I am upgrading okhttp library from v3 to 4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val
> ```

This means you should change the function call `url()` to a property access `url`.

okhttp 4 comes with `replaceWith` param in the deprecation annotation that makes e.g. Android Studio to offer that fix automatically with right-click/alt-enter on the error:

```
@Deprecated(
  message = "moved to val",
  replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "url"),
  level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
```

From comments:

> Upon further investigation I found out that the request() or Request object is from Retrofit 2. And Retrofit 2 returns call object from okhttp3

That's an issue with Android Studio. You can work around it with explicit cast to okhttp 4 types, e.g. `(call.request() as Request).url`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @laato . Unfortunately when I use `url` I get the error saying url is package-private so cannot be used.

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to use it this way `call.request().url.toString()`, but I get compile time error that `url` is package-private so can't be accessed as a property.

Comment: Are you sure your build is using OkHttp 4.x everywhere? Might be validating against both 3.x and 4.x simultaneously?

Comment: @JesseWilson I see what you mean. Upon further investigation I found out that the request() or `Request` object is from Retrofit 2. And Retrofit 2 returns call object from okhttp3 :x

Comment: @laalto That worked like a charm. I guess, I am still getting used to Kotlin ways of casting object. I have marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Seems to work on my end, too. Just curious, how do we know that this cast of a Java Request to a Kotlin Request is 100% safe?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just had to remove the brackets:

`call.request().url()` -> `call.request().url`