# library with okhttp 4 breaks code that uses retrofit 2

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit 2.9.0 in my project which still depends on okhttp 3.14.9
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.9.0

The library I have to include uses okhttp version 4.9.1.

Gradle always uses the highest version of okhttp which breaks my project.
If I force gradle to use okhttp version 3.14.9 like below it breaks the library.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.19'
}
```

**Is it possible to use both versions of the library in one project?**

Also some of the errors are kind of wired.
BuildOutput shows for example the following error:

```
Using 'uri(): URI' is an error. moved to toUri()
```

But AndroidStudio does not highlight it.

[Screenshoot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CB2U.png)
mAuthenticator.getApiClient().adapterBuilder.build().baseUrl().uri().toString()

Some more errors that appeared

```
Using 'uri(): URI' is an error. moved to toUri()
Using 'method(): String' is an error. moved to val
Using 'body(): RequestBody?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'headers(): Headers' is an error. moved to val
Using 'cacheControl(): CacheControl' is an error. moved to val
Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'code(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'code(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function
Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'method(): String' is an error. moved to val
Using 'body(): RequestBody?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'headers(): Headers' is an error. moved to val
Using 'cacheControl(): CacheControl' is an error. moved to val
Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'code(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'code(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function
Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'networkResponse(): Response?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'headers(): Headers' is an error. moved to val
Using 'size(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'networkResponse(): Response?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'headers(): Headers' is an error. moved to val
Using 'size(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'headers(): Headers' is an error. moved to val
Using 'size(): Int' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
```

Comment: I found out that the request() or Request object is from Retrofit 2. And Retrofit 2 returns call object from okhttp3 :x This helped me to fix most of it            
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235314/okhttp-4-x-giving-error-when-trying-to-access-url-via-call-request

Answer (score 0):

https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/

> With a few small exceptions (below), OkHttp 4.x is both binary- and Java source-compatible with OkHttp 3.x. You can use an OkHttp 4.x .jar file with applications or libraries built for OkHttp 3.x.

> OkHttp is not source-compatible for Kotlin callers, but upgrading should be automatic thanks to Kotlin’s powerful deprecation features. Most developers should be able to use IntelliJ’s Code Cleanup for a safe and fast upgrade.

Ideally you should just upgrade your source code to fix these issues using the automatic fixes suggested by Android Studio or Intellij.

Comment: That's what I tried first. Unfortunately there is no automatic fix suggestion by Android Studio for all errors as mention above.

Comment: Most of them you can just delete '()' and it will work.  The manual upgrade should be straight forward